# Response headers Content-Type changes based on the program I use to send the request

Tags: asp.net, rest, postman

got an issue here I would appreciate some other minds looking at.

I have a web server set up to return the response with a content-type of 'application/xml'.

When I send a request from an app we use to sync data I get 'application/xml' in my response header and a XML formatted body, as I should (See below for a capture of this from Fiddler):
[image: Fiddler]

When I send a request from Advanced Rest Client(ARC), I also get the desired response (see below):

[image]

However, when I send the exact same request in Postman I get an 'application/json' as the content-type in my response headers and the body is formatted as JSON. (See below):
[image]

Here is a screenshot of my controller that returns the response:

[image]

Has anyone ever encountered something like this? I don't have any settings in IIS that set the response headers. I did notice the Language detection setting in Postman only has AUTO and JSON. Should there be an XML option? Any help is greatly appreciated.
Version of ARC (14.0.2)
Version of Postman (7.21.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `content-type` header describes what is in the body of a message.
Changing that on the incoming request is going to make no difference.

I expect in the case of a controller like this, the request body has already been parsed into the `Sale` object by a deserializer based on that header.

The [`accept` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) is set by the client to indicate what values it can understand as a response.
There are usually several values in a priority and with a weighting system.
Browsers, for example, have priority for "text/html".

In web API, if you just `return this.Ok(someModel);` the accept header is used to determine which serializer it should use to format the response.

You can change all these settings, but in your case it sounds like you need to change the accept header being set by Postman to make XML a higher priority for these requests.

Comment: I found the "Accept" header was set to "*/*". I guess this accept all format gives more weight to JSON in Postman? Changing it to Accept application/xml did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: If postman is not really specifying a preference then the application itself will probably choose one based on some other priority it has made. Maybe even the order that the formatters are loaded or something equally as arbitrary. Setting a value in Postman is probably the right and safest way to get what you need! Glad this helped.